# CakePDF, CakePHP 3.x, PDF wasn´t rendered

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I´ve installed the CakePDF plugin as it´s described at https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf.

The PDF wasn´t rendered.

composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.16",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.1",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
        "friendsofcake/cakepdf": "^3.1",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2"
    },
```

With the cmd I´ve checked for updates:

```
Nothing to install or update.
```

In config/bootstrap.php:

```
Plugin::load('CakePdf', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);

Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.Tcpdf',
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ],
    'download' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
]);
```

The AppController:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        [...]
    }
```

The DeceasesController:

```
public function test($id = null){

        $decease = $this->Deceases->get($id, [
            'contain' => [
                ]
        ]);
        $this->set('decease', $decease);

        $this->viewBuilder()->options([
            'pdfConfig' => [
                'orientation' => 'portrait',
                'filename' => 'test'.$id
            ]           
        ]);     
    }
```

The View in Template/Deceases/pdf/test.ctp:

```
<h3>Test</h3>
```

The new class in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper/AppHelper.php:

```
class AppHelper extends Helper {

    public function assetUrl($path, $options = []){

        if(!empty($this->request->params['_ext']) && $this->request->params['_ext'] === 'pdf'){
            $options['fullBase'] = true;
        }

        return parent::assetUrl($path, $options);
    }
}
```

In config/routes.php:

```
Router::mapResources(['Deceases']);
```

My folder structure (updated):

```
| Source Files
| | bin
| | config
| | logs
| | plugins
| | src
| | | Console
| | | Controller
| | | | Component
| | | | AppController.php
| | | | DeceasesController.php 
| | | | [other Controllers]
| | | Model
| | | Shell
| | | Template
| | | | Deceases
| | | | | pdf
| | | | | | view.ctp
| | | | | add.ctp
| | | | | edit.ctp
| | | | | index.ctp
| | | | | view.ctp
| | | | Layout
| | | | | pdf
| | | | | | default.ctp
| | | | | [other folders and files]
| | | | [other template folders]
[......]
```

As I figured out, CakePDF require the sub dir named 'pdf' in the template folder. How do I invoke the PDF?

When I browse to `localhost/cake3/deceases/test/test.pdf` I recieve the following error: `Error: The view for DeceasesController::test() was not found.`.

Where is my fallacy? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

When I browse to `http://localhost/cake3/deceases/1.pdf` (thanks for that hint @ndm), I get this error:

```
    Fatal error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Error\pdf\error500.ctp" is missing. #0 
D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(584): Cake\View\View->_getViewFileName('error500') #1 
D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\friendsofcake\cakepdf\src\View\PdfView.php(117): Cake\View\View->render('error500', 'error') #2 
D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(358): CakePdf\View\PdfView->render('error500', 'error') #3 
D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(327): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessageSafe('error500') #4 
D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(329): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage('error500') #5 
D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ExceptionRenderer.php(194): Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage('fatalE in D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 156
```

**Edit #2:**

routes.php:

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);


    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);


    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
Router::mapResources(['Deceases']);
```

**Edit #3:**

Now I´ve created the missing template and add the new dir 'Pdf' into `src/Template`.

When I browse to `http://localhost/cake3/deceases/1.pdf` I get this error (`error.log`):

```
2016-01-28 10:20:52 Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Pdf\.ctp" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'file' => 'Pdf\\.ctp',
)
Request URL: /cake3/deceases/1.pdf
Referer URL: http://localhost/cake3/users/login
Stack Trace:
#0 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(584): Cake\View\View->_getViewFileName(NULL)
#1 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\friendsofcake\cakepdf\src\Pdf\CakePdf.php(818): Cake\View\View->render()
#2 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\friendsofcake\cakepdf\src\Pdf\CakePdf.php(244): CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf->_render()
#3 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\friendsofcake\cakepdf\src\View\PdfView.php(131): CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf->output('')
#4 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(612): CakePdf\View\PdfView->render(NULL, NULL)
#5 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(120): Cake\Controller\Controller->render()
#6 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\DeceasesController))
#7 D:\Programme\Programme\Xampp\htdocs\cake3\webroot\index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#8 {main}
```

What file is meant with `file "Pdf\.ctp"`?

**Edit #4:**

After revising the whole project, I get no error anymore. Thanks a thousand times to @ndm.

I´ve removed the optional routing because I see no need to use it.

When I browse to `/deceases/view/1.pdf` I retrieve the same view like `/deceases/view`, not the view of an PDF with the buttons to download or print given by the browser.

Should that be this way? And when it´s should be like this, how do I get the PDF shown in the browser?

Comment: So, given that you mention mapped resources... do you actually want to access the files in such RESTful route manner? If so, the path should be like `/test/1.pdf` (pointing to the `view` action... in any case you'd have to pass the id, not `test`). Also, when are you loading the plugin routes in your `routes.php` file?

Comment: If I remove `Router::mapResources(['Deceases']);` and browse to `/test/1.pdf` I also get the error `The view for deceasesController::test() was not found.`

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions...

Comment: Yes, sorry. I don´t know, how to route in another way. 
The plugin routes are loaded with `Plugin::routes();`in the line above the `mapResources`. Is that what you´ve wanted to know?

Comment: Pretty much, it would be helpful too to know where your other routes are. Anyways, with the resources mapped after connecting the plugin routes (which registers the `pdf` extension), invoking `/deceases/1.pdf` (made in mistake in my first comment, sorry) should work, given that a corresponding `view` action and template are available.

Comment: How do I figure out where the other routes are?

Comment: By looking in your `routes.php` file, that's what I'm referring to. As for your new error, that's what happens when using extensions, the error controller will load the request handler component and switch layouts/templates accordingly. Either create the template that the error message says is missing, and then check your logs, or [**use a custom error controller**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-a-custom-controller-to-handle-exceptions) that doesn't load/unloads the request handler (for `pdf` extensions).

Comment: "_What file is meant ... ?_" None I guess, this looks like the template name is missing. Looks like this could happen when the view template doesn't output any data (check whether this is the case for you), so that `CakePdf::_render()` is being invoked, which should only happen [**when `$html` is `null`**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/blob/3.1.0/src/Pdf/CakePdf.php#L243). This should be reported as a bug. ps, it's advised that you edit your question to add further information, answers should only be used for actual answers.

Comment: **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/pull/148**

Comment: I´ve edited my question accordingly and deleted the answer. Thanks for that hint.

Okay, I´m checking out wether `$html` is null.

Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: Thanks one more time for your effort to rectify my issue.

Comment: I´ve added your alterations into my code but I recieve the same error as before. What do I overlook?

Comment: I would kinda doubt that you experience the exact same error, as the stacktrace that you've shown, shows that an empty string is passed to `output()`, and with the changes in the PR applied, it wouldn't reach the code part anymore where the shown error is being triggered.

Comment: Uhh, I´ll check that.

Comment: Finally I defeated the monster. ^^ There´s an update in my answer. ;)

Comment: You need to [**register the `pdf` extension**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions), or move the `Plugin::routes()` call upwards. I'd suggest to do the former, as it might become the required thing to do anyways. **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/issues/147**

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. That works. Finally! :D 

But why those things aren´t explained in the documentation?

Comment: They just missed that one I guess. Pretty sure this will be added to the docs when the issue gets processed.

Comment: Great. You´re my hero. ;)